# Passing string as URL parameter to Url.Action does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am attempting to pass a string as an action parameter to Url.Action using the following line:

```
url = '@Url.Action(nameof(Controllers.DailyController.UserBreakEnd), "Daily", new { breakToEnd = 1, confirmation = "BreakCanceled" })';
```

The breakToEnd parameter is coming through in the function, but confirmation is not.  Am I passing the string incorrectly?

Also, when I do it like this, both parameters come through:

```
url = '@Url.Action(nameof(Controllers.DailyController.UserBreakEnd))?breakToEnd=@(Model.MessageType == "BreakUnder" ? 1 : 2)&Confirmation=BreakCanceled';
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though instead of placing an & symbol in between the parameters in the URL string that was generated, this was putting `&amp;` between them.

The issue was resolved by surrounding the Url.Action with Html.Raw, like so:

```
url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action(nameof(Controllers.DailyController.UserBreakEnd), "Daily", new { breakToEnd = 1, confirmation = "BreakCanceled" }))';
```